# $_GET[] php and url

Tags: php, url, get

I'm creating reference to next page so `<a href="changePakett.php?pakett_id=<?=$pakett['pakett_id']?> ">change</a>`
After clicking to the link in url I have a result `/changePakett.php?pakett_id=1`. This is result I needed, but i have a problem. Now I need value of pakett_id inside my query, but I can't get it

```
if(isset($_GET['pakett_id'])){
    $pakett_id = $_GET['pakett_id'];

    if(isset($_GET['changepakett'])){
        $connection = db_connect();
        if($connection)
        {
            $kirjeldus = $_GET['kirjeldus'];
            $hetke_hind = $_GET['hetke_hind'];
            //invisible there

            echo $pakett_id;

        }else echo "Can't connect to DataBase";
    }
}else echo "Sorry, don't understand which pakett you want to change =(";
```

My `$_GET['pakett_id']` is visible when I'm checking if it isset, but invisible inside another if(see comment in code). How can I get it where it's invisible?

UPDATE:
`changePakett.php form`

```
<form action="../lib/functions.php" method="get">
            <input type="text" name="kirjeldus" placeholder="kirjeldus"/>
            <input type="text" name="hetke_hind" placeholder="hetke_hind"/>
            <input type="submit" name="changepakett" value="change"/>
        </form>
```

Comment: print $_GET to see what it contains. And what do you mean with invisible there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no `$_GET['changepakett']` so the code inside that `if` statement never executes. `changePakett.php` is the name of the file that you are in.

Use this as you develop and it will make your life much easier:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');
```

Comment: I have form on `changePakett.php` , submit button for this form has `name='changepakett'`. If I'm submitting form there isn't `$_GET['pakett_id']` anymore. How can I get it?

Comment: check `print_r($_GET)` on top of your page and see what it prints

Comment: There is no `packet_id` in your form.  Add it as a hidden input.

Comment: Array ( [pakett_id] => 1 ), after submitting, there is array with data from form but I need [pakett_id] for query which will Update data field in DB WHERE pakett_id equal `$_GET['pakett_id']`